# Choosing UV resin or epoxy for diffusing LED on PCB

Tags: led, lightning, uv

I have a sandwich structure made out of two boards. The first one has an LED on its top side. The second one is 5 to 10mm thick and sits on the first board. It has a milled slot above the LED on the PCB. There's nothing else on the PCB so the boards are perfectly sealed with the LED in the center of the milled slot. I need to pour a resin, UV cured maybe, or epoxy, in that slot to slightly diffuse the light without changing the light intensity or its color too much. The slot is 10mm long 3mm wide and 5 to 10mm deep so I need to use a needle or a very small applicator. What product should I use to meet these requirements ? Something non toxic would be preferable.

Comment: Also consider (electronic grade) silicone. Less rigid materials can improve reliability.

Comment: I suggest starting the 3M online support. If it exists, they have it. You need a applicator? They sell it as well. I have good experience with the company - most products are available at the common distributors as well.

Comment: I'd epoxy a block of frosted acrylic in there. 3mm wide? Cut a piece from a sheet and insert it edge wise. You can actually sand and muck with it to get the finish you want before gluing it in. With epoxy, seems like there would be trouble with bubbles and finish especially if you applied it with a stick, especially if its viscous so it doesn't flow through. But if you mask both sides with tape (I assume this is being done before the sandwich? I sure hope so)  so you can pour in a thinner epoxy, there are still bubble issues and other risks.

Comment: But if there nothing else on the PCB can't you just epoxy a film or sheet over the slot? Why does it need to go *into* the slot? And is the seal important?